qz.printers.clearQueue() function not working in Windows
When I create a print job and the printer is offline, I want to clear the job so that the print wont get executed when the printer is back online. To solve that, I keep note of the jobId and after 15 seconds after its in printing stage, if the print is not complete, I try to clear the job.
I am using code
qz.printers.clearQueue({
  printerName: "Bill",
  jobId: 19
});

In mac, this code works and job is cancelled, but in windows, it throws the error
Job# 19 is not part of the 'Bill' print queue

And if I just try to pass the name for qz-tray to clear all queue using this code, it doesn't perform any action
qz.printers.clearQueue({
  printerName: "Bill",
});

Here the printerName and the jobId are passed with correct values.

This questions was also asked on our subreddit.  https://www.reddit.com/r/qztray/comments/1gr6r0a/.  To summarize the reply that's already left there, when pausing the printer, submitting a job and then sending qz.printers.clearQueue(...) command, the API behaves as expected.  This means there's either a bug with the API specific to your use-case, or your example is missing some context needed for others to reproduce.
